# Display information from D3.js to web inspector.

Tags: d3.js

Some body help me?

Could you tell me why after declrar the variables "x " and "y", the tags " svg " and all that follows it along the code no longer appears in the inspector my web browser?
When I remove the variables just mentioned , the " svg " tag and its " id = bar" atributes appear correctly with all that follows in the code.

------------- the code: ------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="./scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>

<script type="./scripts/d3js.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/d3css.css">
<title>d3</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = [213,20,60,232,150,74,110,39];
var w = 1000;
var h = 500;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.length])  
    .range([0,w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])  
    .range([0,h]);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "chart")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return i * 40;
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 39)
    .attr("height", function(d,i){
        return y(d);
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

------------ THAK YOU / Greetings from Mexico City -------

Comment: which web browser are you using? - works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Hi!

Thank you so much for the answer.

I love that there are nice people that likes to help.

Greetings from Mexico City.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display information from d3.js to web inspector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440030/display-information-from-d3-js-to-web-inspector)