# Display information from d3.js to web inspector

Tags: d3.js

Could you tell me why after declare the variables x and y, the `<svg>` tag and all that follows no longer appears in the inspector of my web browser? When I remove the variables just mentioned the `<svg>` tag and its id = bar atribute appears correctly as does all the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="./scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>

<script type="./scripts/d3js.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/d3css.css">
<title>d3</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">



var data = [213,20,60,232,150,74,110,39];
var w = 1000;
var h = 500;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, data.length])
    .range([0,w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])  
    .range([0,h]); 


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "chart")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);


svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return i * 40;
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 39)
    .attr("height", function(d,i){
        return y(d);
    })


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using D3 v4.x. in that version, there is no `scale.linear()`. Instead of that, it should be:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
```

And the same for the `var y`.

As this line comes before your `var svg` (which appends the SVG element), it throws an error and the SVG tag is never created. Look at the console and you'll see the error.